# How to specify port number on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to run two emulators simultaneously, one on port 5554, and one on 5556. The first one is already set; but how do I configure the second one to be on 5556 (in Elipse)?

Answer (score 11):

Change directory to android-sdk/tools

Issue the following command

```
./emulator -port 5556 -avd AVD2_1_HVGA
```

AVD2_1_HVGA is my AVD name in Eclipse.  You can see your AVD name by selecting the menu Window > AVD Manager.

Comment: This is not working for me. After navigating to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

...at the command line, I entered:

./emulator -port 5556 -avd Gingerbread_API10_Android2dot3dot3

...but was greeted with:


""." is not recognized as an internal or external command,..."

So, I tried the same thing but without the leading "." and then I got the similar err msg ""/emulator" is not recognized as an internal or external command,..."

?

I don't normally run the emulators from the command line; it's odd to me that this isn't easy to do, or at least possible, via Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `-port 5556` on the command line that launches the second emulator. You should be able to adjust the command line in the Launch Configuration panel.

Comment: Where is Launch Configuration panel?

Answer (score 1):

It seems if I start another *AVD* (NOT another Android app directly from Eclipse, which then naturally invokes an AVD), and THEN start the second app from Eclipse, and choose the just-invoked AVD to run it, it will automatically use 5556 (with the previously running Android app defaulting to using 5554). So: problem solved; it seems there is no need to go to a command line, it's simply a matter of doing things in a particular order.

Comment: Depending on non automated "doing things in a particular order" is a well known receipt of desaster in computing.