# Debugging Android Emulator with USB or Wireless connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, libusb-1.0, mvt

Is there any way to connect Android Emulator via USB or Wireless?

I know that Android Emulators are connected to local ADB automatically, but some ADB-based tool (e.g., [MVT](https://github.com/mvt-project/mvt)) requires "real" USB or wireless connection to work.

I have the following 2 questions regarding these 2 approaches:

#### USB Connection

In [MVT](https://github.com/mvt-project/mvt)'s case, it uses Python's `libusb1` library, and `libusb1` can only detect "real" USB device.

The question is, is there any way to make emulator as local USB device?

#### Wireles Connection

I tried wireless debugging as well. Since AVD's (QEMU) network is not accessible from host's network, I tried Genymotion (VirtualBox) and pair with `adb pair 127.0.0.1:PORT`, with pairing code from Emulator's developer options, and I got:

```
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Success
```

So, is there any way to `adb pair` emulator with host?

Comment: From what I can tell MVT uses the Python package `adb_shell` which reimplements the adb protocol with additional features. Relevant issue: https://github.com/JeffLIrion/adb_shell/issues/81 and in particular comment by package author: https://github.com/JeffLIrion/adb_shell/issues/81#issuecomment-678681899

Comment: `adb pair` is only for physical network devices running Android 12+. Have you tried to simply connect to the adb tcp port ever emulator provides? You can specify the used port when you start the emulator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8109570/150978

Comment: @Robert Do you mean like `nc 127.0.0.1 5556`? Yes, I can connect to it.

Comment: BTW if I `adb tcpip 5555` and `mvt-android check-adb --serial 127.0.0.1:5555 --output mvt-avd-test`, it will be stuck in `INFO     [mvt.android.modules.adb.chrome_history] Running module ChromeHistory...` forever.